# Not showing not found route when loading route from server side in react router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

my problem is that when I want to get a route from the server dynamically, when that route is loaded, not found route is displayed in a fraction of a second, which is not good at all, and the reason is simple, and that is that the route that path If it is equal to *, it will be shown in all routes if there is no route. I don't know if you understood my meaning or not because I am writing part of my sentence with Google Translate. Look at the code below to better understand my problem.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import { Books } from "./components/Books";
import { Book } from "./components/Book";

const App = () => {
   const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);

   useEffect(() => {
     loadBooks();
   });

   function loadBooks() {
     axios.get("http://localhost:3001/books").then((data) => setBooks(data));
   }

    return (
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                <Route path="/books">
                  <Route index element={<Books />} />
                  {books.map((book, index) => (
                    <Route
                      key={index}
                      path={book.name}
                      element={<Book name={book.name} />}
                  />
                  ))}
                <Route path="*" element={<h1>Not found!<h1/>}/>
            </Routes>
        </Router>
    );
}
```

When they have a list of books, they are taken from the server. If I manually search for example localhost:3000/books/book1 in the search field at the top of the browser, it first shows the not found page very quickly, then the route of the book itself. How can I do this without showing the not found page when the desired route is loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid rendering potentially unreachable routes I'd suggest conditionally rendering some fallback UI until the book data has been fetched.

```
const App = () => {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    function loadBooks() {
      axios.get("http://localhost:3001/books")
        .then((data) => setBooks(data));
    }

    loadBooks();
  }, []);

  if (!books) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }

  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/books">
          <Route index element={<Books />} />
          {books.map((book) => (
            <Route
              key={book.name}
              path={book.name}
              element={<Book name={book.name} />}
            />
          ))}
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" element={<h1>Not found!</h1>}/>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Alternatively I'd say it may be better to not conditionally render a bunch of routes and to instead unconditionally render just a single route with a dynamic path param that correlates to a specific book name. e.g. `"/books/:name"`.

Example:

```
const BookLayout = () => {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    function loadBooks() {
      axios.get("http://localhost:3001/books")
        .then((data) => setBooks(data));
    }

    loadBooks();
  }, []);

  return <Outlet context={books} />
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/books" element={<BookLayout />}>
          <Route index element={<Books />} />
          <Route path=":name" element={<Book />} /> // <-- "/books/:name"
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" element={<h1>Not found!</h1>}/>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

`Books` and `Book` will use the [`useOutletContext`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-outlet-context) hook to access the `books` array. `Book` would use the [`useParams`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params) hook to get the current book `name` route path param value and render any fallback UI while the books data is fetched.